# Como hacer que se repita un ciclo hasta que el usuario ingrese un texto

Tags: javascript, condiciones, bucles, while

Es posible tener un if dentro de un while?. Quiero hacer que si el usuario ingresa un número que vuelva a escribir hasta que escriba un string, pero cuando ejecuto el código no funciona.

```js
function contarCaracteres(valor = prompt("Escriba algo")){
         if (valor == 2){
             while (val == 2) {
                 let val = prompt("Vuelva a escribir");
                 val();
             }
         } else{
               document.write("El texto ${valor} tiene ${valor.length} caracteres");
         }
     }
     contarCaracteres();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo varios problemas en tu código:

```
function contarCaracteres(valor = prompt("Escriba algo")){
         if (valor == 2){
```

Esto no es un error, pero en general no es una buena práctica: la función `prompt` devuelve texto, no un número. Tu código funciona hasta aquí porque == usa *coerción de tipos* y transforma los elementos comparados para que tengan el mismo tipo. Es más correcto transformar el texto leído a `number` y usar el triple igual `===` para comparar de manera estricta: `if (+valor === 2) {`.

```
             while (val == 2) {
```

Eso sí es un fallo: la variable val no existe, con lo que esta comparación es igual a comparar `undefined == 2`, lo que siempre dará `false`. Esto hace que las siguientes dos líneas no se ejecuten nunca y por tanto `val` nunca tendrá asignado un valor. Podrías reutilizar `valor` aquí.

```
                 let val = prompt("Vuelva a escribir");
                 val();
             }
         } else{

               document.write("El texto ${valor} tiene ${valor.length} caracteres");
```

Esta línea tiene otro fallo: estás intentando usar un *string template* pero al usar comillas dobles (`"`) en lugar de las comillas inversas, los *placeholders* no serán interpretados.

```
         }
     }
     contarCaracteres();
```

Y ahora en conjunto: no hay problemas por usar un while dentro de un if, pero si estás comprobando en ambos lo mismo, el if es innecesario. Has de familiarizarte con el control del flujo del programa (se consigue con la experiencia, no te preocupes) y saber cuándo aplicar condiciones y/o bucles:

```js
function contarCaracteres(valor = prompt("Escriba algo")){
  while (+valor !== 2) {
    document.write(`El texto ${valor} tiene ${valor.length} caracteres\n`);
    valor = prompt("Vuelva a escribir");
         
  }
}

contarCaracteres();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, recién estoy comenzando a programar. Otra duda que tuve fue que agregue el 2 porque no encontre como hacer un bucle que diga que si valor es un número que vuelva a escribir.

Answer (score -1):

Dentro de un if puede ir un while porsupuesto. Este código creo que  le puede servir. Para validar que un dato ingresado sea un número puede utilizar las expresiones regulares: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

```js
   

 var val;

var regex=/^[0-9]{1,99999999999999999999999999999999999999999}$/;

function contarCaracteres() { 

    do {
        
            val= prompt("Por favor escriba un texto");
      }
      while ((val??'').length<=0||(val??'').match(regex));
     
      document.write(`El texto ${(val??'')} tiene ${(val??'').length} caracteres<br>`);
   
     }
     
     contarCaracteres();
```

Comment: En realidad lo que queria hacer es que si el usuario  ingresa un número que vualva a escribir hasta que escriba un string. El problema es que puse el 2 para probar porque no encontre como hacer un bucle que diga que si valor es un número que vuelva a escribir.

Comment: Creo que esa regex se podría escribir como `/^\D+$/g`